# Why does gson think my json feed is an object when it's clearly an Array?

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I have a JSON feed which my android application is reading:

[
  {
    "AddressLine1": "91 Park Road",
    "AddressLine2": "Sutton Coldfield",
    "AddressLine3": "Birmingham",
    "Bio": "With a hard-worked-on combination of authentic tastes and quality service, you will be sure to enjoy Asian Grill amongst friends and family, time and time again.",
    "CompanyDescription": "Indian Restaurant",
    "CompanyID": 2,
    "CompanyName": "Test Test",
    "CoverFileExtension": "jpg",
    "CoverFileName": "cover_asiangrill",
    "Deliveroo": null,
    "Facebook": "186939334708528",
    "Instagram": null,
    "JustEat": null,
    "LinkedIn": null,
    "LogoFileExtension": "png",
    "LogoFileName": "logo_asiangrill",
    "OpeningHours": "17:00 - 23:00",
    "PostCode": "B73 XXX",
    "Telephone": "0121 354 xxx",
    "Twitter": null,
    "UberEats": null,
    "Unavailable": false,
    "Website": null
  },
  {
    "AddressLine1": "Gracechurch Shopping Centre",
    "AddressLine2": "Sutton Coldfield",
    "AddressLine3": null,
    "Bio": "Freshly Squeezed & Pressed Juices, Fresh Fruit Smoothies, protein smoothies and Crepes!",
    "CompanyDescription": "Smoothie and Juice Bar",
    "CompanyID": 6,
    "CompanyName": "Juiceys",
    "CoverFileExtension": "jpg",
    "CoverFileName": "cover_juiceys",
    "Deliveroo": null,
    "Facebook": "squeezeandgrinduk",
    "Instagram": "juiceysuk",
    "JustEat": "juiceys-sutton",
    "LinkedIn": "",
    "LogoFileExtension": "jpg",
    "LogoFileName": "logo_test",
    "OpeningHours": "09:00-17:30",
    "PostCode": "B72 XXX",
    "Telephone": "0121 355 XXX",
    "Twitter": null,
    "UberEats": null,
    "Unavailable": false,
    "Website": null
  }
]

My kotlin code below fetches the json string nicely:

```
fun fetchJson(){
        val url = Singleton.getUrlBase() + Singleton.getUrlPlacesBasic() + "400"
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body  = response?.body?.string()

                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                try {
                    val placesFeed = gson.fromJson(body, CompanyInfoBasicFeed::class.java)
                }
                catch(e: Exception){
                    val errString = e.toString()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("Failed to execute")
            }
        })
    }
```

**But unfortunately I get the error:** `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $`

My data classes are as follows:

```
//JsonObjects
class CompanyInfoBasicFeed(val companiesInfoBasic: List<CompanyInfoBasic>)

data class CompanyInfoBasic(val CompanyID: Int,val CompanyName: String?,val PostCode: String?,val
                            CompanyDescription: String?,val LogoFileName: String?,val CoverFileName: String?,val
                            LogoFileExtension: String?,val CoverFileExtension: String?,val
                            AddressLine1: String?,val AddressLine2: String?,val AddressLine3: String?,val Telephone: String?,
                            val Facebook : String?,val Twitter: String?,val Instagram: String?,val LinkedIn: String?,val JustEat: String?,val
                            Deliveroo: String?,val UberEats: String?,val Website: String?,val
                            Bio: String?,val OpeningHours : String?,val Unavailable: Boolean )
```

It thinks that my object to parse into is not an array/list? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`CompanyInfoBasicFeed` is not a `List`. `CompanyInfoBasicFeed` *contains* a `List`, but that would require an outer JSON object with a `companiesInfoBasic` property to match your constructor property. Your JSON object does not have such a `companiesInfoBasic` property.

You will need to have Gson parse a `List<CompanyInfoBasic>` and get rid of `CompanyInfoBasicFeed`. Or, possibly, have `CompanyInfoBasicFeed` extend `List<CompanyInfoBasic>`.